# Criteria mismatched between two dates

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

It always show criteria mismatch in criteria expression. Here's my code.

```
OleDbCommand pending = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE business_active = 0 AND date_of_application BETWEEN '" + FromDateTxt.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' AND '" + ToDateTxt.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'", cn.con);
        OleDbDataReader dr_pending = pending.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Most likely related to formatting of the date. You make it a string now. You can better use parameters for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it avoids datatype mismatches. if your column is not only a data, make the parameter a datatime:

```
            SqlParameter fromDate = new SqlParameter();
            fromDate.ParameterName = "@FromDate";
            fromDate.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
            fromDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            fromDate.Value = FromDateTxt.Value;

            SqlParameter toDate = new SqlParameter();
            toDate.ParameterName = "@ToDate";
            toDate.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
            toDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            toDate.Value = ToDateTxt.Value;

            OleDbCommand pending = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE business_active = 0 AND date_of_application BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate", cn.con);
            OleDbDataReader dr_pending = pending.ExecuteReader();
```