# Compare DateTime with Microsoft SQL and Visual C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, oledb

I'm trying to compare a DateTime to a given date.

```
string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"data 
source=C:\\myDB.mdb";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString);
conn.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
String q = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE CheckIn < DATE()";
//String q = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE CheckIn < '01.01.2020'";
//String q = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE CheckIn < 01.01.2020";
//String q = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE CheckIn < '01.01.2020 00:00:00'";
//String q = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE CheckIn < 01.01.2020 00:00:00";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(q, conn);
Console.WriteLine(q);
adapter.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("0 found");
}
```

The code shows how I compare it to the current time. It works fine and results in

```
01.12.2018 00:00:00
```

. But if I try to replace the currentTime to a specific value (see what I've tried), it throws me either System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException or SQL Syntax Error. I'm a bit confused right now because DATE() returns a value in the very same format as I've tried. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Best regards

Kruspe

Comment: Msdn has specific examples about iso date format

Comment: Use Parameters, see my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53352625/criteria-mismatched-between-two-dates/53352784#53352784 (you could even say your question is duplicate)

Comment: Dates do not have a format.  Use Parameters and pass a Date and it will work.  Your code is passing text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

It's called the ISO-8601 standard date format, and you should always use it when putting in Date literals, in pretty much any language:

```
2020-01-01
```

---

While I'm here, the code posted has the potential to leak connection objects in the situation where an exception is thrown. It's better practice to enclose your connection in a `using` block. As an aside, if you use parameterized queries for this, the formatting suddenly becomes irrelevant.

```
string dbPath = @"C:\myDB.mdb";
string conString = $"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source={dbPath}";
string q = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE CheckIn < ?";
Object result = null;

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(q);
    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}

if (result == null || result == DBNull.Value)
{
    result = "0 found";
}
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect.

Comment: I jut have to open and close the connection

Comment: @kruspe when you close a connection "by hand" and your code gets an exception before that, the connection is not closed. By using 'using' you are certain the connection is closed whatever happens

Comment: @Kruspe Do **NOT** add code to open/close the connection. The `.Fill()` method already handles this for you, and the `using` block does a better job ensuring the connection will close than your old code did.

Comment: But, the way you wrote it, it throws me an error, saying "Connection status: closed"